# How to perform some expression in django project?

Tags: python, django

I am new in python and Django and I want to make some expression query in my project active expire or expire soon. How can I do that?

Here is my model and model function of code.

```py
class recharge_monthly(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(Client_Detials, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Total_amount = models.FloatField()
    Received_amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    received_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_vat_add = models.BooleanField()
    is_tsc_add = models.BooleanField()
    tsc_amount = models.FloatField()
    vat_amount = models.FloatField()
    def con_tsc(self):
        if self.is_tsc_add:
            tsc = self.Total_amount * self.tsc_amount / 100
            return tsc
        else:
            tsc = 0.0
            return tsc
    def con_vat(self):
        if self.is_vat_add:
            add_tsc = self.Total_amount + self.con_tsc()
            vat = add_tsc * self.vat_amount / 100
            return vat
        else:
            vat = 0.0
            return vat   
    def total(self):
        total = self.con_tsc() + self.con_vat() + self.Total_amount
        return total

    def due_balance(self):
        due = self.total() - self.Received_amount
        return float(due)

    def status_active_dactive(self):
        recived_date = self.received_date
        user_rec_date = recived_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        time_today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
        one_month = time_today + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        five_day = time_today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        day_five = five_day.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        month = one_month.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        expire = "Expire in"
        Active = "Active"
        expire_soon = "Expire Soon"
        if day_five >= user_rec_date != month:
            return Active
        elif day_five == user_rec_date != month:
            return expire_soon
```

Comment: That's not a model class.

Comment: It looks like you posted some other code than you wanted to post? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want:

```
delta = datetime.datetime.now().date() - self.received_date
if delta.days < 5:
    return "Active"
elif delta.days == 5:
    return "Expire Soon"
else:
    return "Expire in {} days".format(30 - delta.days)
```

Not sure about the number of days you wish for expiry, you can set parameters as you wish.
The main idea is to calculate the number of days between today and the date in the model and then make decision accordingly